# Typical flow for generating large set of unique ERC-721 metadata and setting tokenURI

Tags: contract-design, erc-721

First of all, I have searched around in previous posts and haven't found an answer to this so apologies in advance if this is a duplicate.

I am minting a collection of NFTs via ERC-721 and have the broad flow working fine from a web front end.  The rub I encounter is around dynamically generating the metadata / art associated with the individual tokens.  Now, I know I can pass in a folder to IPFS and use the tokenid to associate the minted token to the IPFS URI but the question is this:

**Is it acceptable / typical to generate the random art combination ahead of time, upload to IPFS and then associate with tokenID in the minting or is it expected and the norm to try and generate the art real time at the time of minting and then associate with the new token?**

I originally looked at the concept of generating art assets, uploading to IPFS, getting URI and associating with the token at mint but it seemed like this approach would have required a lot more complexity in terms of trying to maintain collection state (via hosted DB I guess) to avoid duplicate metadata / art (as that is dynamic).

So is it "OK" to just generate and upload the NFT assets ahead of time so the minting process is just a matter of connecting the token ID to the metadata URI?

Thanks in advance.